# Как сделать элемент в блоке полупрозрачным при наведении курсора, при этом чтобы псевдоэлемент остался непрозрачным?

Tags: html, css, hover, псевдоэлемент

Пытался дать псевдоэлементу (подчеркивание) отдельные свойства по `hover'у`.

Проверил в dev tools, что псевдоэлементу при ховере присваивается значение:

```
opacity:  1;
```

но все равно весь элемент становится полупрозрачным:

```css
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 26px;
  font: 500 18px/21px Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.menu__item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, width .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__item" href="#">blog</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что бы сделать сам элемент полупрозрачным и при этом сохранить "непрозрачность" псевдоэлемента `after` при событии `hover`:

```css
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  font: 500 18px/21px Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 26px;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  color: #d8d8d8; // или rgba(0, 0, 0, 50%)
}

.menu__item::after {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.menu__item:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__item" href="#">blog</a>
```

Или:

```css
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  font: 500 18px/21px Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 26px;
}

.menu__item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.menu__item:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.menu__item::after {
  content: "";  
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.menu__item:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__item" href="#">blog</a>
```

Если же Вы хотите получить эффект fade in/out при событии `hover` по псевдоэлементу, то:

```css
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  font: 500 18px/21px Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 26px;  
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.menu__item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
  transition: opacity .5s, width .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__item" href="#">blog</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Для текста используйте прозрачность через цвет с использованием `rgba()`.

```css
.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 26px;
  font: 500 18px/21px Roboto, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); // opacity: .5;
}

.menu__item:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #0056EC;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, width .5s;
}

.menu__item:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__item" href="#">blog</a>
```